# MVC Form post Html.BeginForm ASPX view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This question might be very simple to many of you, but I am just learning.  Trying to convert  form  to Html.BeginForm

The old script is

```
<form method="POST" name="myquiz">
```

Trying to convert it to

```
<% Html.BeginForm(new {name="myquiz"}); %>
<input type="button" value="Grade Me!" name="B1" onclick="gradeit()" class="t-button"/>
<input type="button" value="Reset" name="B2" onclick="document.myquiz.reset()" class="t-button"/>
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

When I click on reset button, I get the following error:

```
 Unable to get property 'reset' of undefined or null reference
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too few params, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) for details, so it should be:

```
HTML.BeginForm(null,null,FormMethod.Post, new {@name="myquiz", id="myquiz"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your anonymous class object paramter is passed as the route values, not HTML attibutes, you need, at a minimum, this many parameters to get what you want ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470539%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)):

```
Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "myquiz" })
```